# I am omitting some words when typing unintentionally

Tags: neuroscience

When I type mostly I omit word / words.

e.g.
I wanted to if it is correct -> I wanted to know if it is correct. 
It should background task -> It should be done in background task.
etc.

Because of this I read word by word everything I have typed. Sometimes I even omit words like *not*, *don't* etc.

Very rare I have the same issue with reading.

**Edit:**
It happens no matter in what language I am typing. (native, foreign)

What kind of health issue I am having?

Comment: Is it health issue really?

Comment: I thought it is some neurological issue

Comment: I sometimes have this issue when typing in english (not my native language), but not really often. Usually when I'm in hurry. It could be ADHD, but only specialist can say the real diagnosys.

Comment: Lol, older question is duplicate of newer.

Comment: @rus9384: that's because this one was closed twice, (look at [its history](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/posts/18437/revisions)) first time was for being off-topic.